# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\phpB89.tmp' to 'image/pg26_tag_c1102735_1474_17.jpg

Tags: php

i am facing 2 error with uploading image to Xampp server. The first time i tried is just fine, but after that i am facing

move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\phpB89.tmp' to 'image/pg26_tag_c1102735_1474_17.jpg

move_uploaded_file(image/pg26_tag_c1102735_1474_17.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D

But the image that i uploaded is inserted into the Xampp, but why still i am having those errors ?

```
<?php

$msg ="";

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$target = "image/" .basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","agentsdb");

$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO images_tbl(image) VALUES ('$image')";
mysqli_query ($db,$sql);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
$msg = "image uploaded successfully, pls go back to login page";
}else{
$msg = "There is a problem";
}
}
?>

<form action="imageform.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">


<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" 
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>

<td>
<input name="image" type="file"> <input type ="submit" name ="upload" value 
= "upload">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>

<?php
echo $msg;
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have this error because target directory does not exist and `move_uploaded_file()` can't move file.

You need to create directory called `image` in directory with your php file manually or programmatically

```
if (! is_dir('image') ) mkdir ( 'image' , 0755);
```

Comment: you have enough rep to make this a comment; it is not considered as an answer/solution

Comment: I think it is the only error and if so it will be solution.

Comment: Note: [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014138/move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move-d-xampp-tmp-phpb89-tmp-to-image-pg26-ta/44014172?noredirect=1#comment75056311_44014172) above (and the flag as not an answer) was based on the original post of http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44014172/1 being just: *"Please check if you have directory called image near your php file"*. And the post [was edited 4 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44014172/2), as of this comment's timestamp.

Comment: tq so much :) appreciate :)

Comment: @PerryPuah if it works for you, please accept my answer